# What does (R-TN) after a name mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, abbreviations, culture

An example:

> US Rep. Marsha Blackburn **(R-TN)** wants to make sure the Federal Communications Commission never interferes with "states' rights" to protect private Internet service providers from having to compete against municipal broadband networks.

From: http://arstechnica.com/business/2014/07/congresswoman-defends-states-rights-to-protect-isps-from-muni-competition

Looks like some kind of an abbreviation to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It means that the person is a **Republican** member of Congress from the state of **Tennessee**.

The "(X-YY)" convention is widely used in the news media to refer to current and former members of the U.S. House of Representatives and Senate, with *X* denoting the person's political party (usually R for Republican or D for Democratic) and *YY* denoting the state he or she represents. (See [this page](http://www.stateabbreviations.us/) for the official list of two-letter state abbreviations.)

Comment: We are increasingly also seeing "I" for Independent, which means they don't come from the Republican or Democrat parties - the name of their party isn't used, instead opting for I. Candidates from the Green Party are labeled with "I" for example, not G.